# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 3 Problem 9 (c)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I've been stuck with this 9 (c) problem:

[image]

I think the floor function might be a counterexample since: if $f(x) = ⌊x⌋$ then $f = f²$
and the $C_{A}$ function just doesn't look like it.

I checked the answer book and it says to apply (b).

If you have a better answer or could explain to me how to apply (b), would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The floor function does not satisfy $f=f^2$.

Comment: If you interpret $f^2$ as the *composition* of $f$ with itself —that is, $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$— then it's true that $f^2=f$ when $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. However, the question appears to intend that $f^2$ means the *product* of $f$ with itself: $f^2(x) = (f(x))^2$.

Comment: Thank you @Blue, now I see why I couldn't solve it LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $x = x^2$ only has two solutions, $x = 0$ or $x = 1$. Thus if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies the relation $f(x) = f^2 (x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, it follows that $f(x) = 0$ or $1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. The result follows from (b).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Reavered.